# Vue Fullcalender: Be able to have different prices on each day grid based on their day

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Now I want to know how to render the dynamic data on each day grid with vue.js or js?
Most answers I see online are about Jquery with outdated methods from past versions.

This basically what I want
[fullcalendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKDll.png)

In eventRender you can access props but you can't in dayRender?

```js
          eventRender(info) {
                info.el.firstChild.innerHTML = `
                    <a class="rounded-lg fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event f-start fc-end">
                        <div class="h-12">
                            <span class="fc-title text-white flex ml-3">
                                <img class="img-circle avatar-small h-8 w-8 p-1" src="${info.event.extendedProps.imageurl}">
                                <span class="ml-3 self-center font-bold">${info.event.extendedProps.username}</span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                `
            },
```

I could not find props so I used a data variable, but I need it, to be dynamic.

```js
        dayRender(dayRenderInfo) {
                dayRenderInfo.el.innerHTML = `
                <div class="relative h-auto w-auto bg-gray-400">
                    <span class="text-green-600 font-semibold absolute day-price">$${this.calendarPrice}</span>
                </div>
                `
            },
```

Here is code of what I want to do, yet is in jquery and seems date and cell where removed.

````
        dayRender: function(date, cell) {
            var dayInfo = $.grep(days, function(e) {
                return e.day === date.format()
            }); 
            console.log(dayInfo);

            <% if !@rooms.blank? %>
                if (dayInfo.length > 0) {
                    if (dayInfo[0].status == "Not_Available") {
                        cell.addClass('fc-past');
                    } else {
                        cell.append('<span class="day-price">' + '$' + dayInfo[0].price + '</span>' )
                    }
                } else {
                    cell.append('<span class="day-price">' + '$<%= @room.price %>' + '</span>')
                }
            <% end %>
        },
    ```
````

Comment: "date and cell where removed" [sic]... actually they were moved, not removed. See fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/dayRender . `date` is `dayRenderInfo.date`, and `cell` is `dayRenderInfo.el`. Also remember that `el` is now a DOM element not a jQuery object. Once you know those things, it wouldn't be too hard to adapt that code.

Comment: Thank you, ADyson checked your profile and noticed your avatar.
I notice your posts have helped me a lot,  before since I have seen other of your posts in StackOverflow related to fullcalendar. I used your suggestion to write this new code and Currently having problem with rendering, and made new post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62548646/fullcalendar-dayrender-not-rendering-the-price-in-correct-day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution thanks to ADyson
Here is the code for anyone that may need it in future.

```js
            dayRender(dayRenderInfo) {
                const dayInfo = this.CalendarDays.filter(CalendarDay =>  moment(CalendarDay.day).isSame(dayRenderInfo.date, 'day'));

                if (dayInfo.length > 0) {
                    if (dayInfo[0].is_available === false) {
                        dayRenderInfo.el.innerHTML = "";
                        dayRenderInfo.el.classList.add("fc-past");
                    }
                    else {
                        dayRenderInfo.el.innerHTML = `
                        <div class="">
                            <span class="text-green-600 font-semibold day-price">$${dayInfo[0].price}</span>
                        </div>
                    `
                    }
                } else {
                    dayRenderInfo.el.innerHTML = `
                        <div class="">
                            <span class="text-green-600 font-semibold day-price">$${this.calendarPrice}</span>
                        </div>
                    `
                }
            },
```