# FullCalendar dayRender not rendering the price in correct day

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Problem is that the price is rendering in incorrect row.

As in the screenshot above, I am having 2 problems.

1. I have dates from July 12-14 and I disabled them.
   The dates do get disable but the price which should be removed instead is removed in dates
   July 5-7. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMv3Z.png
2. I changed price from July 9-11 but it renders as if the price is on July 2-4
   [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvRKL.png

```js
            dayRender(dayRenderInfo) {
 
                const dayInfo = this.CalendarDays.filter(CalendarDay =>  moment(CalendarDay.day).isSame(dayRenderInfo.date, 'day'));
                
                if (dayInfo.length > 0) {
                    // console.log(dayInfo[0].is_available === false);
                    if (dayInfo[0].is_available === false) {
                        dayRenderInfo.el.innerHTML = "";
                        dayRenderInfo.el.classList.add("fc-past");
                    } else {
                        dayRenderInfo.el.innerHTML = `
                        <div class="relative h-auto w-auto bg-gray-400">
                            <span class="text-green-600 font-semibold absolute day-price">$${dayInfo[0].price}</span>
                        </div>
                    `
                    }
                } else {
                    dayRenderInfo.el.innerHTML = `
                        <div class="relative h-auto w-auto bg-gray-400">
                            <span class="text-green-600 font-semibold absolute day-price">$${this.calendarPrice}</span>
                        </div>
                    `
                }


            },
```

Something that confuses me a lot is that adding classList does work properly.
Yet issue is with rendering the pricing with innerHTML

```js
    dayRenderInfo.el.innerHTML = "";
    dayRenderInfo.el.classList.add("fc-past");
```

Comment: Can we see the definition / contents of your `CalendarDays` array please? Please provide as usable Javascript code. That way I can make runnable code to try to reproduce and understand your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Solved it, it was a CSS issue.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue.
It was related to CSS issue.

Solved it by changing this class.

```
    .day-price {
        position: absolute;
        color: #00A699;
        bottom: 4px;
        right: 2px;
    }
```

and removing some css classes

```
            dayRender(dayRenderInfo) {
                const dayInfo = this.CalendarDays.filter(CalendarDay =>  moment(CalendarDay.day).isSame(dayRenderInfo.date, 'day'));

                if (dayInfo.length > 0) {
                    if (dayInfo[0].is_available === false) {
                        dayRenderInfo.el.innerHTML = "";
                        dayRenderInfo.el.classList.add("fc-past");
                    }
                    else {
                        dayRenderInfo.el.innerHTML = `<span class="text-green-600 font-semibold day-price">$${dayInfo[0].price}</span>`
                    }
                } else {
                    dayRenderInfo.el.innerHTML = `<span class="text-green-600 font-semibold day-price">$${this.calendarPrice}</span></div>`
                }
            },,
```